# Local coordinates in NoSql database

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, spatial-database

Is there any nosql database which supports the below

1) Should support local coordinates (spatial data  which holds the coordinatesof door, Infra, etc.)

2)Integration with Geoserver.

Comment: Seeing your previous question, are you sure you need to go nosql? You should try PostgreSQL/Postgis, if you are coming from Oracle you might be surprised by the difference :-)

Comment: Have you looked already and eliminated anything yet?

Comment: @AndreaAime - We have done a POC with PostGis but haven't observed much difference in performance

1) Loading data from AutoCAD to POSTGIS

2) And budget as we want to go with Vendor

Comment: @Spacedman - Yes, we looked both Solr and MangoDB but both have limitations that load only Geo coordiantes and doesn't support local coordinates.

Comment: What do you mean by "local coordinates"? Simply an X and Y offset from some locally defined reference point? Any database can do that.

Comment: POLYGON ((44225.300000005 61616.3199999181 0.0, 43615.3000000049 61616.3199999181 0.0, 43615.3000000049 60606.3199999181 0.0, 44225.3000000049 60606.3199999181 0.0, 44225.300000005 61616.3199999181 0.0))

Answer (score 1):

The Elastisearch geo-shape datatype seems to support any kind of unit (at least judging from the precision field): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html

NGA provides an Elasticsearch datastore that connects to Elastisearch:
https://github.com/ngageoint/elasticgeo

However, I never tried either personally, and the GeoServer community has no contact with the elastigeo developers and thus cannot endorse or offer help with the store usage.

Comment: Later in the geo-shape document `Note: Elasticsearch uses WGS-84 coordinates only.`.

Comment: Ah, did not notice that... pity...